# how to create a view like this shape in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

how to create this **2D look**

[image]

How to I create this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can draw using CAShapeLayer.

Comment: can we add this 2d look with CAShapeLayer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
class TwoDView : UIView {
    public var xDiff : CGFloat = 5.0
    public var yDiff : CGFloat = 5.0

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        ctx?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height - yDiff))
        ctx?.addLines(between: [
                CGPoint(x: rect.width - xDiff, y: rect.height - yDiff),
                CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height),
                CGPoint(x: xDiff, y: rect.height),
                CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height - yDiff)
            ])
        ctx?.setFillColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        ctx?.fillPath()


        ctx?.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width - xDiff, y: 0))
        ctx?.addLines(between: [
            CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: yDiff),
            CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height),
            CGPoint(x: rect.width - xDiff, y: rect.height - yDiff),
            CGPoint(x: rect.width - xDiff, y: 0)
            ])
        ctx?.setFillColor(UIColor.gray.cgColor)
        ctx?.fillPath()


        UIImage(named: "Image")?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width - xDiff, height: rect.height - yDiff))

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: hello can you help me tho answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786763/how-add-mirror-image-to-2d-box-corners